# .NET How to generate schema for app.config?

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config, configurationmanager

Using the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) [code/annotation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration) configuration, I can define a rich, typed model for my app.config structure. 
Is there a way (or tool or special incantation) to generate the corresponding XSD from this code-based model?

Having an XSD-schema makes it *awesome* to edit configuration files! (never thought I'd say that :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, I found the lovely-looking [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) VS plugin and it generates XSD in addition to code!
But this is a designer-only solution and lacks a bit of flexibility (plus I'm afraid a designer-based solution is harder to scale).

### LATER EDIT

I ended up giving [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) a more serious chance and I'm loving it! As it turns out, it's plenty flexible for my purpose. Here's shot of a part of my configuration definition:

[image]

Pros:

- Easy to use
- Generates XSD for the config file
- Generates a (bare-bones) app.config file
- Flexible, supports lots of the customizations exposed by ConfigurationManager. Here are some of the ones I used:

  - Enum support (that trickles all the way to the generated XSD, so you get IntelliSense when filling in attribute values
  - 'Default collection' for sections, so you can support `<section><item/><item/><section>` instead of `<section><items><item/><item/></items><section>`
  - Out of the box support for type 'System.Type' for attributes (and the associated converter)
  - option to generate strongly-typed element collections (implementing ICollection)
  - input validators, including custom (roll-your-own)
  - Type converters for loading/storing elements with properties of any types, including Roll-your-own
  - Config element inheritance

I'm sure there are other things that I forgot about.

A few drawbacks:

- The documentation is not exhaustive (although it does send you in the right direction)
- The errors that sometimes show up are not very explicit (along the lines of "something went 'splat' in CodeDom"), but so far it's always been a problem in my model (e.g. I forgot to assign a property).

But these are minor nuissances.

Overall, I got the job done quickly and easily. Thumbs up!